# Renavigate() in angular2

Tags: navigation, angular, reload

I have some input fields in my component. I get the values of theese fields from server simply by http.post. And I have onCancelClick() method and I am looking for the way to reload data without page refresh. I was trying to use router.renavigate() but it does not call ngOnInit() method. I don't understand what it is doing actually.(I have imported CanReuse, but neither it helped). From my onCancelClick() method if I call directlly this.ngOnInit() it works but I think it is not a good practice. Has anyone any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish. Ideally a Plunker that allows to reproduce (template https://plnkr.co/edit/m4HHsZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you http://pastebin.com/xqMSnfid

Comment: I would just move the data to a service and bind to that data and just update the data in the service without any navigation. (Or alternatively subscribe to the service to update changed data locally https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use ngDoCheck which is will listen directive changes.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements DoCheck {
  ngDoCheck() {
    // ...
  }
}
```